# Override isReachable not working for mock

Tags: swift, alamofire

I would like to test my code and the behavior. In that case I override the NetworkReachabilityManager of Alamofire and the open var isReachable. In my test case the isReachable method of NetworkReachabilityManager would be called, but not of MockNetworkReachabilityManager.

```
func testIsReachable() {
    let mockNetworkReachabilityManager = MockNetworkReachabilityManager()
    XCTAssertFalse(mockNetworkReachabilityManager!.isReachable)
}

class MockNetworkReachabilityManager: NetworkReachabilityManager {
    override var isReachable: Bool {
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `isReachable` from the base class `NetworkReachabilityManager` is called instead of the subclass `MockNetworkReachabilityManager`? How did you know it?

Comment: Yes sure https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/NetworkReachabilityManager.swift

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be, if you use an protocol and override the `isReachable` method. Then I can write an `MockNetworkReachabilityManager``

```
protocol CustomNetworkReachability {
  var isReachable: Bool { get }
}

extension NetworkReachabilityManager: CustomNetworkReachability {}

class MockNetworkReachabilityManager: CustomNetworkReachability {
  var isReachable: Bool {
    return false
  }
}
```